# How to do sorting by date ( ascending and descending order) using chevron up and down icons

Tags: angular, sorting, date

I want to create a table with a chevron up icon .When i click on the icon , the array of dates should be in ascending order and when i click on the icon again , this time its chevron down , the dates should be in descending order. How can achieve this in angular. So i have below code with a chevron icon and date ( returned as array of objects)

```
<div class="col-md-12 no-padding sortby">Sort by:Latest<span class="fa fa-chevron-up"></span></div>
<div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
                              <span>{{sample.dates}}</span>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Show us your code please!

Comment: @TanDuong In my case, date is coming as an array of objects as a JSON. So i have included the binding part alone

Answer (score 0):

for the style :

```
<span class="fa fa-chevron-up" *ngIf="order" [ngClass]="{'asc': order > 0, 'desc': order < 0}"></span>
```

In your classes

```
.fa.fa-chevron-up.asc {
  // Nothing
}
.fa.fa-chevron-up.desc {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

For your typescript code (that you will have to bind to a button)

```
order = 0;
sort(order: number) {
  this.order = order;
  this.data = this.data.sort((a, b) => order < 0 ? 
    a.createdAt.getTime() - b.createdAt.getTime() : order > 0 ? 
    b.createdAt.getTime() - a.createdAt.getTime() : 0);
}
```

Now your data will be filtered and your chevron will be displayed

*(disclaimer : I'm not sure of the orders and orientation of your chevron, so don't hesitate to invert the conditions in the code and in the classes)*

Comment: Ahah seriously ? You give a random piece of code and you expect a fiddle ? Give me a [mcve] on stackblitz and I'll give you the result of this code. Be lucky that I answered, I usually ask for closure of such questions.

Comment: sort must return: a negative number, 0 or a positive number(not true or false): use a.createAt.getTime()-b.createAt.getTime()

Comment: Don't mind my previous comment, thank you for correcting me !

Comment: What is order here?

Comment: The direction of your sorting.